# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' in iOS 13.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5, xcode11, ios13.2

I was running an app on iPhone XR with iOS Version 13.2 using XCode 11.2 and the app crashes with reason.

> reason: 'The return values of -viewForFirstBaselineLayout and
>   -viewForLastBaselineLayout must be in the receiver's subtree

I tried searching but couldn't find the solution here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17633/nsinternalconsistencyexception-any-ideas-on-what-is-causing-this

I don't know what files I need to post here for this issue. So please mention in the comment if any file is required to understand this.

```
func removeSubviews() {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            subview.removeSubviews()
            subview.removeFromSuperview()//this line is causing crash.
        }
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
    }
```

Comment: have you added the exception break point? you may get the line which is causing the error.

Comment: Show your code for `viewForFirstBaselineLayout`.

Comment: @matt There is no such file as `viewForFirstBaselineLayout` but I think the above-mentioned code is causing the issue. is there any way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The removing always should be in reverse order to adding. So view added to superview and then activated constraints, thus I would do it as

```
func removeSubviews() {
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        for subview in self.subviews {
            subview.removeSubviews()
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

also you should check other things you add, when constructing view hierarchy, so if any other cross-references created then they should be also destroyed, again - in reverse order.